# Find the row with the largest matching string across two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have this:

```
page_url                      | canvas_url
---------------------------------------------------------------
http://www.google.com/        | http://www.google.com/barfoobaz
http://www.google.com/foo/bar | http://www.google.com/foo
```

I'd like to find the row that is the start of my string ordered by the longest match. The problem I'm facing is finding the longest matching string, rather than just the row that matches that also has a matching one. I.e.

http://www.google.com/foo matches `page_url` in row 1 and `canvas_url` in row 2, but if it's length of both columns rather than a match it would think row 1 is the better match as `canvas_url` in row 1 is longer.

I could grab all matches and then filter the length in code doing something like:

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(canvas_url), LENGTH(page_url)
FROM app 
WHERE
    'http://www.google.com/foo' LIKE CONCAT(canvas_url, '%') OR
    'http://www.google.com/foo' LIKE CONCAT(page_url, '%')
```

Or perform 2 subselections grabbing the top matches of `canvas_url` respective `page_url` and then filter that to 1 in code, but I would prefer (barring any ridiculous performance issues) having the database just return what I need.

My immediate concern is MySQL but I need to target SQLite and Postgress, so I'd be happy with an answer in either of those.

Suggestions?

Comment: I don't get it. Why does the page_url of row1 match `http://www.google.com/hi`? The page_url in row1 doesn't have `hi` at the end... Are you trying to find the url that has the most characters in common with your search string? Or somethign else? Perhaps you could expand on your example to more clearly show what strings match what urls, and then what makes one url prefered over another url?

Comment: @Dems Ah got spotting, I thought myself into a corner. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Dems Updated with better examples, sorry about that.

Comment: In your new example, you don't *state* that the search string matches the canvas_url in row1.  I assume that you *do* count that as a match?  Also, which RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle?

Comment: @Dems - Right again, I was inverting my lookup, it should've been `'<url>' LIKE '<column_content>%'` too see if the URL is columns content is the start of the string. MySQL would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work to get the longest actual match length (not just the longest url in the record):

```
-- Get page_url matches
SELECT *, LENGTH(page_url) AS MatchLen
FROM app 
WHERE 'http://www.google.com/foo' LIKE CONCAT(page_url, '%') -- can't tell from question if this should be reversed
UNION ALL
-- Get canvas_url matches
SELECT *, LENGTH(canvas_url) AS MatchLen
FROM app 
WHERE 'http://www.google.com/foo' LIKE CONCAT(canvas_url, '%')
-- Bring the longest matches to the top
ORDER BY MatchLen DESC -- May need to add a tie-breaker here
LIMIT 1
```

Here is a [running example on SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0b96/4).

Comment: The CONCAT has to be on the column since I want to know if the column value is the start of my string rather than the string being the start of the column value. The UNION idea is pretty dope though.

Comment: @KitSunde, then I don't see how any canvas_url is a match.

Comment: Ah yeah it was matching `page_url` on row two. I swapped the values in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need something like this?

```
SELECT page_url as url, LENGTH(page_url) as len
FROM pages WHERE 'http://www.google.com/foo' LIKE CONCAT(page_url, '%')
UNION
SELECT canvas_url as url, LENGTH(canvas_url) as len
FROM pages WHERE 'http://www.google.com/foo' LIKE CONCAT(canvas_url, '%')
ORDER BY len DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thank you for your comment... order by desc... well not exactly, it's not clear how to count the longest match, but i think i have an idea now, i'll edit my answer

Comment: Yes, I'm confused by the question and the example matches given.  That said, there may need to be a tie-breaker in the `order by` as well.

Comment: I'm still undecided of how to order the results... maybe now it's better!

Comment: Your original answer was correct, btw. Except I guess I wanted the ordering to be `DESC`, but that's minor detail.

Comment: Ok, i edited again with DESC but i'm still not sure that it's exactly what you want.. with DESC it returns row 2, is that what you want? you asked for the longest match but then you say that row 1 is the best match?

Comment: Your original post had CONCAT(page_url, '%') like my example above, that should also still be the case.

Comment: Okay i wasn't sure about what was your request...now it's clear :) tnx!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find just the first row, you want an order by and limit.  You have to be a bit clever about how to arrange it:

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(canvas_url), LENGTH(page_url)
FROM app 
WHERE canvas_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo' '%') OR
      page_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo', '%')
order by (case when canvas_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo' '%') and
                    page_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo', '%') and
                    LENGTH(canvas_url) < LENGTH(page_url)
               then LENGTH(page_url)
               when canvas_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo' '%') and
                    page_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo', '%') and
                    LENGTH(canvas_url) >= LENGTH(page_url)
               when canvas_url like concat('http://www.google.com/foo' '%')
               then LENGTH(canvas_url)
               else LENGTH(page_url)
          end)
limit 1
```

This is ordering by the longer of the matching strings, and then returning exactly one row.  Note that `LIMIT` is not standard, so different databases have different mechanisms for returning one row.

Comment: This sorts by the longest url, not the longest _matched_ url. Also, the `LIKE` predicate seems reversed to me.

Comment: I had no idea case even existed so that's pretty cool. `LIMIT` should work in all 3 databases I'm targeting. `CONCAT` however does not so for ANSI SQL enabled databases (Postgress, SQLite) I use `||`, while MySQL doesn't support `||` without enabling ansi support.

Comment: order by GREATEST(LENGTH(page_url), LENGTH(canvas_url)) ?

Comment: @fthiella . . . `GREATEST()` is not standard SQL and may not be available in all the databases.

Comment: @TimLehner . . . You are correct on both accounts.  I had used the logic in the question, clearly without reviewing it.  The logic in the order by was just wrong.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, at this point, I'm definitely unsure about the requirements. I hope I didn't lead you to unnecessarily edit your answer.